# Symfony2, Clone EntityManager or how create new instance of it

Tags: symfony, entitymanager

Of course we can do this :

```
public function __construct (EntityManager $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}
```

and use EntityManager what ever we want. But... I need create standalone EntityManager in custom class\service, we can get it this way

```
public function __construct (EntityManager $em)
{
    $this->em = clone $em;
}
```

but it's not good choice because all data was inputed\added\called before this call will be "copied" to $this->em and we don't want it...

So question is, how to create standalone EntityManager in class\service not by arguments (in services.yml)?

I need something like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->em = new EntityManager()
}
```

**UPDATE:**

So i found solutions i need. But how can i apply this for EntityManager or other "build in" services?

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why do you need a "standalone" EntityManager? Maybe you're asking how to inject the EntityManager into services? Have you read http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#referencing-injecting-services?

Comment: Maybe this? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Comment: No guys, do you know difference between $object1 = $object2 and $object1 = clone object2 ? And yes, links you gave i read and know this. :(